# refresh and alter layout on click of checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I didn't really know how to phrase this.
Basically I have this method:

```
private void uploadFile(int maxSpinner) {
    setContentView(R.layout.upload);

    CheckBox local = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.local_checkbox);
    Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    local.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            checkbox = isChecked;

            if( isChecked){

                uploadFile(6);
                Log.i("checked", "yes");

            }
            else {
                uploadFile(5);
                Log.i("checked", "no");
            }
        }
    });

    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int category = 1; category <= maxSpinner+1; category++){
        categories.add(Integer.toString(category));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            category = arg2+1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

The corresponding layout file has a checkbox and a spinner.

`maxSpinner` is the limit for the for-loop that sets the amount of Spinner elements. I want to change `maxSpinner` depending on whether the checkbox gets selected or not.

So in the beginning `uploadFile()` gets called elsewhere with 5 as the argument.  When I click the checkbox `local` I want to call `uploadFile` again, but this time with either `6` or again `5` as an argument, so I get a different amount of elements for the spinner.

The way I tried it is seen above. Nothing happens when I click the checkbox, I can see in the log it always logs "yes", even though the checkbox never actually gets visibly checked.

any help would be appreciated,

thanks

Comment: You're not changing CheckBox or Spinner, So don't extract them in this method, take them (click listener also) back to onCreate() method. Just create new Adapter in uploadFile() and set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it does work just as expected, it just doesn't update the checkbox because I'm not telling it to do so.